# Exchange data between android devices of one user without cloud programming

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, backend

i want to program an application that connects different android devices of one user. If happens an event on one device, the other one should be notified (eg. a toast for testing).

Is there a service in the world of google that handles the backend for me, without programming my own server/cloud-app?

An example would be timely from google where i can change the clock on my mobile and seconds later the new value ist available on my tablet.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `Google Could Messaging(GCM)`, and get start from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a service, that can be used for sending notification to another phone. Here is an official link.
[Google Cloud Messaging for Android](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
And this is an example
[Android Device to Device Messaging using GCM via HTTP](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)